# DataTable Goes out of Memory after just 2.5M records

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, out-of-memory, sqldataadapter

I'm trying to bring data from database into a dataTable and records are about 6 million. 
As we know DataTable Limit is **16,777,216**

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

But my dataTable goes out of Memory on just 2.5 million records. I dont know why?

```
public DataTable Func(int totalRecords)
{
     SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
     sda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();

     sda.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SP_NAME";
     sda.SelectCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans;
     sda.SelectCommand.Connection = this.connection;
     sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     SqlCacheDependency dependency = new SqlCacheDependency(sda.SelectCommand);

     if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
         connection.Open();

     dt.Load(sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
     return dt;
 }
```

Comment: Well just because that's the theoretical maximum doesn't mean you necessarily have enough memory to store all the data from the table. What's in each row? Do you really *have* to load all the data in memory at the same time? (That's very rarely a good way of handling non-tiny tables.)

Comment: Each Row Contains 7 Columns.

Comment: That doesn't tell us much... each of those columns could be just an integer, or a huge amount of text... again, I would focus on try to avoid having to load all the data in one go to start with.

Comment: Yes Because I need to perform some analysis alogrithem on it and need to store all of the data in cache too.

Comment: You generally have better chance to reach limits in x64 process... Make sure you are not running x86 (32bit).

Comment: You can stream the data into a cache... and does your analysis algorithm really need all the data at once? I'm not saying you don't need it all - just that you may not need *everything* in memory all at the same time.

Comment: Fname (Varchar), LastName (Varchar),MiddleName(Varchar) , StreetAddress ((Varchar)) , DOB(DateTime) , Gender((Varchar)) , phone (Varchar)

Comment: What is the size of the varchars and which fields are you analyzing?

Comment: Well my basic purpose that i Need to achieve is to bring all the data and store it in cache for future use.

Comment: @JonSkeet 
I can manage that algo thing. But how about bringing all the data in cache you can say on page_Load ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Well I wouldn't try to download 6 million records *while loading a page*. What kind of application is this to start with? I think we need a lot more context to help you, to be honest... but you need to think about when you really want to perform very long-running operations.

Comment: You might be better off doing it in a CLR stored procedure

Comment: Okay Let me give you context : 
Actually I am having a sort of record search application. So to make its search faster, I dont want to hit the database everytime  to fetch records. That is why i think it will be good to bring all the data in cache for once. It will help me search faster. That is it.. :)

Comment: That's a terrible idea for a massive table, instead hit the DB each time where all sorts of data algorithms will optimise the searching, like Indexes for one.

Comment: maybe you are right. But it does reduce my search timespan.
and also the thing is I need to perform many kinds of matching criterias to bring the resultset. and those I cant perform in DB.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build a local version of your whole database. That sounds like a bad idea - using a well-indexed database is likely to be rather better, as that's precisely what it's designed for. Do you have concrete performance targets at the moment? How far are you off them at the moment with the simple "hit the database" approach? Have you profiled the queries you need?

Comment: _I need to perform many kinds of matching criterias to bring the resultset. and those I can't performed in DB_ The last part may or may not be true. If it is you still should try to __filter as much in the DBMS as you can__ to reduce the load on memory and also traffic!

Answer (score 0):

Is it an executable? If so make sure that

```
 Project Settings -> Build -> Prefer 32-bit
```

is unchecked